# Is it a bad idea to use for loop/non ES6 for React

Tags: reactjs

I have two props that both are arrays. 
prop1 = json objects array
prop2 = components array (as they are icons in svg format).

What I want to do is iterate prop1 and insert icons in props2 as I go.
As map function in javascript only takes one array object. Is it bad idea to use traditional for loop, e.g. for(i=0; i

```
const input = [
  { value: 'One', label: 'One', default: true },
  { value: 'Two', label: 'Two' }
]

const icons = [<Icon1/>, <Icon2>]
```

What I wanted to do is insert these icons based on what's in the array.

Comment: Why not have 1 Icon component that accepts a prop to display the heading dynamically and just map your array on the state to show each Icon

Comment: show us how prop1,prop2 looks like “iterate prop1 and insert icons in prop2” is unclear

Comment: Hi, @DennisVash. I edited code above. Essentially these two are used as props for another component to consume and generate some button groups.

Comment: Ok, what does "insert these icons based on what's in the array." means? What is your condition? (btw I edited my answer meanwhile)

Comment: What I want to achieve is take each array element in input array, generate into a button and have the button icon show next to it.

Comment: So Icon1 corresponds to button 1 with the value of 'One', label text of 'One' and Button 2 have value of Two and Lable text of 'Two' and have Icon2 next to it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible ways to achieve what you asking for example:

```js
const generateButtons = (buttonsProps, iconArray) =>
  buttonsProps.map((buttonProp, i) => {
    const { value, label, ...restProps } = buttonProp;
    return (
      <div>
        {iconArray[i]}
        <button value={value} defaultChecked={restProps.default}>
          label = {label}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  });

function RenderButtons() {
  return <div className="App">{generateButtons(buttonsProps, iconArray)}</div>;
}
```

[image: Edit new-sunset-3x6j2]

Comment: I believe you missed the `key` attribute

Comment: Thanks guys, I forgot to say that I have another loop using map function with index, and I want to use that index to output each item in IconArray.

Comment: `iconArray[i]`? Or I dont understand the question

Comment: @DennisVash Sorry for all the confusion, hope the above edits makes bit more sense.

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to have array of components, it's best to let your state handle the logic/array and just reuse same component and render each input dynamically.

```
const Icon = ({label}) => <h1>{label}</h1>;

const Icons = ({inputs}) => inputs.map(input => <Icon label={input.label} />) 

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    inputs :  [
      { value: 'One', label: 'One', default: true },
      { value: 'Two', label: 'Two' }
    ]
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {<Icons inputs={this.state.inputs}/>}    
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```